# Editing imported attributes in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, fields-attributes, excel

I have finally completed my first ArcGIS-task, creating a shapefile containing poligons which mark designated spaces as well as installed facilities. The more than 450 facilities have a whole lot of attributes, luckily accecssable in an Excel sheet which also contains XY-data. I though I had successfully joint this data with the shapefile (as they have one attribute in common), just to realise right after that I can neither edit these nor use them for analyzing.

I have already tried creating a point feature class. As the data is in spanish, I assume the problem might be related with the content (e.j. ñ?).

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed not possible to edit data from a joined table. The easiest workaround is right clicking the layer name -> Data -> Export Data... and save it as a new shapefile. This new shapefile will then include all data from your joined table, and can be edited freely.

Comment: Also see *Join Field*, from [Is exporting to feature class the simplest way to make joins permanent?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107665/is-exporting-to-feature-class-the-simplest-way-to-make-joins-permanent)

Answer (score 1):

While ArcGIS allows you to view Excel tables and join them with Esri formats, there are some limitations.  Editing the content of the Excel data is one of them.  If you just joined the two tables in ArcMap, try exporting the feature class to a new feature class after the join.  That should permeate the join.  Keep in mind though, you won't have much control over the schema for each field so some cleanup may be needed.  You could import the Excel table into a database application, such as Access, first if schema is a concern.  Of course, the two sources won't mirror so you may have to plan on maintaining the previous excel data in ArcGIS and exporting to Excel as needed.